# Identify groups for a given group order

Tags: group-theory

Is there a way to figure out types of groups present for a given order? Are there any good reference books or sites that will give me a complete knowledge about this?

As an example, when we are thinking of groups of order $16p$ where $p$ is a prime, we can think about 2 kinds of groups: groups without a normal sylow $p$-subgroup and groups with a normal sylow $p$-subgroup. Under groups without a normal Sylow p-subgroup we can identify 3 types of groups:

1. Groups of order 48
2. Groups of order 80
3. Groups of order 112

And under groups with a normal sylow $p$-subgroup again we can identify $3$ kinds of groups:

The case where $G/G'$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ etc.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The very first sequence in the OEIS is [A000001](https://oeis.org/A000001)
 "Number of groups of order n." The entry has many references and hyperlinks to get you started whatever level of knowledge of group theory you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there a single reference which will give me the complete knowledge. Like a quick exam study?

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika : I understand your request but I can only suggest a good textbook on Group theory emphasizing finite groups. Have you looked at Schaum's Outline of Group Theory?

Comment: Ok, I'll check that. Thanks a lot.